# How to send request parameters by Ajax to Struts2 action class

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, struts2

I have a Struts2 web application consisting of the following files:

`member.jsp`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    String str1 = "aaa";
    String str2 = "bbb";

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost:8080/project/editprofile.action", true);
    xmlhttp.send(null); 
</script>
```

`struts.xml`:

```xml
<action name="editprofile" method="editProfile" class="controller.ControllerSln">
    <result name="success" type="stream">
        <param name="contentType">text/html</param>
        <param name="inputName">inputStream</param>
    </result>
</action>
```

`ControllerSln.java`:

```
public String editProfile() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

I want to send the strings "aaa" and "bbb" by Ajax to `controller.ControllerSln#editProfile()` method. How can I achieve it?

Comment: I don't understand. Why can't you just pass them as parameters in the request?

Comment: This is my first web project and my information is basic level, i've searched on web but i couldn't understand and apply them on my project so i've asked here.

Comment: But I still don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ControllerSln has String attributes which are called str1 and str2.Also their getter and setter must be created by eclipse automaticly. 
After that , your action has to be like this : **http://localhost:8080/project/editprofile.action?str1="+str1+"&str2="+str2;** 
When your action starts,struts will match parameters because their names are the same..
You can see print str1 and str2 on your editProfile() method.

Comment: How do you know he is using Eclipse?

Comment: We are in communication with Sedat Kurt so he know that i use eclipse for my java project. Thank you Sedat for your solution, it works clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Give the complete javascript ajax call code if it is simle javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function updateProfile()
        {
            var xmlhttp;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else
            {// code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            if (typeof xmlhttp == "undefined")
            {
                ContentDiv.innerHTML="<h1>XMLHttp cannot be created!</h1>";
            }

            else{

                var str1 = "aaa";
                var str2 = "bbb";

                var str='?str1='+str1+'&str2='+str2;
                var query='editProfile'+str;
//str1 and str2 should be there at Controller.ControllerSln to fetch data from ajax 
                xmlhttp.open("GET",query,true);
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
                {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                    {
                        document.getElementById("UpdatedProfile").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                        //UpdatedProfile  div where u want to display result of ajax
                    }
                }

                xmlhttp.send();
            }
        }
```

}

Comment: On the upper solution worked clearly Manish, I saved your solution too. Thanks for your effort.